# Replacement for PHP mail() method?

Tags: php, apache, email

I'm trying to set up a web site on a (shared) web hosting account. And I'm facing an issue with the mail() method. The site has a contact form where a user can submit their feedback:

```
Name: _____________
Email: ____________
Message: __________
```

So I was using the mail() method as such to send it as an email to my own account:

```
if(mail("mysitecustomerfeedback@hotmail.com", 
    "Customer message", 
    $message,
    "From: $name <$email>\r\n".
    "Reply-To: $name <$email>\r\n".
    "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion()) === true)
{
    $messageWasSent = true;
}
```

So when I try it, the email is dispatched, but there are several issues with it.

For instance, for my test I provided my actual email, say, `johndoe@hotmail.com` but when the email is received in my `mysitecustomerfeedback@hotmail.com` Hotmail account, the `from` email field is filled out with the default email on the shared hosting server, or something like `web-user234@server875.web-hosting.com` and not `johndoe@hotmail.com` as I would expect it to be.

Also the email was automatically placed into Junk by Hotmail, even though it contained no attachments, images, or anything. It was a plain text message.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

So I understand that this shared hosting company doesn't want me to send spam using mail() method, but how else can I send these emails off my web site? Is there a replacement method for mail()?

Comment: You cant send from your own Hotmail account because almost all email providers use a system to protect against emails send from non white-listed addresses

Comment: You could use an email service such as https://sendgrid.com/

Comment: @Tchoupi: Thanks. SendGrid sounds really nice. Have you used it, how reliable is it? As long as it doesn't do any shenanigans likes [Mandrill did](http://thenextweb.com/dd/2016/02/25/in-hostile-move-mandrill-gives-all-developers-60-days-to-switch-to-paid-mailchimp-service/#gref) this year I'd be good with it.

Comment: @c00000fd The API is easy to use, the service is very reliable. I used it for a few projects and I love it.

Comment: @Tchoupi: Nice to know that. Thanks. I'm curious though, they have a free and a $9.95/mo account, but when I check the specs, they tend to be the same except the number of emails per month: https://sendgrid.com/marketing/mandrill-alternative Am I reading it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Example:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();

// You can use the SMTP host/auth details
// supplied by your personal email provider.
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.example.com';
$mail->Username = 'myUsername';
$mail->Password = 'myPassword';

$mail->setFrom('my@example.com');
$mail->addAddress('to@example.com');

$mail->Subject = 'A subject.';
$mail->Body = 'A message.';

$mail->send();
```

Since you authenticate with hotmail/gmail or whichever email server you use, the recipient will receive the email just as if you sent it using your favourite email client (this is a PHP email client).